# Is there a name for an analog of dense point where closed is replaced by open?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

A dense point (a.k.a. generic point) of a topological space $X$ is a point $x\in X$ such that $X$ is the only *closed* set containing $x$. Is there a name for the same notion but with "closed" replaced by "open"? It is then equivalent to asking that $x$ belongs to the intersection of all non-empty closed subsets of $X$.

Example: take the quotient topology of $\mathbb R^n$ under the quotient map $p:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n/\mathbb R^*$. You get a projective space and a supplementary point $p(0)$, which is as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point such that the only open neighbourhood is the whole space is called a **focal point**. Such spaces are encountered as a matter of course in algebraic geometry: the spectrum of a ring has a focal point if and only if it is a local ring.